# Looking for an app that does iCloud key value pair syncing

Tags: icloud, key-value

I am looking for an app that does iCloud key value pair syncing?

Can anyone tell me a free app on the app store that does that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in Weather and Stocks widgets do that